# how to get correct output from hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like so...

```
  scores = {:b3=>1000, :c3=>-1000}

  scores.each do |k,v|
    if v = 1000
      best_answer = k
    elsif v = -1000
      best_answer = k
    end
  end
  p 'BEST_ANSWER'
  p best_answer
  return best_answer
```

I keep getting c3

best_answer SHOULD be b3

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to change from assignment to comparison:

Not `if v =` but rather `if v ==`

Second, when you reach your "best answer", you could just return the best_answer and forgo the rest of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you actually using assignment operator instead of equality one.

change `=` to `==`:

```
if v == 1000
  best_answer = k; break
elsif v == -1000
  best_answer = k; break
end
```

also you would like to refactor your code.

```
best_answer = scores.key(-1000)
```

or

```
best_answer = scores.min.first
p best_answer
#=> :b3
```

Comment: hmmm, that would seem correct but I'm still getting c3 as the output :(

Comment: you miss return, sec, updating answer